# Why can you ping www.microsoft.com, but not microsoft.com?

Tags: networking, ping

I noticed you couldn't ping microsoft.com, and another post explained that this is likely because they block ICMP requests for security.

This makes sense, but how come I can ping [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com)? What does the added www change, and why have they not blocked pings to this address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domainname is a name that points to an ip address. A subdomain on a domain also points to an ip address. They do not have to point to the same address though, and in case of microsoft.com, it is even possible that a load-balancing system or fail-over system alters this ip address on consecutive dns queries.

When you connect to an address, or execute a ping, or any other networking, you do this towards the ip address. This ip address will point to a server.

[www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com) goes to a different server than microsoft.com. One server is configured to acknowledge ICMP requests where the other is configured to ignore them. As such, you get a response from one and not the other.

It is possible that if you repeat the same command 10 times in a row, due to load-balancg or fail-over a different ip is returned, where it responds differently to ICMP requests. So the same request can first respond to ping where the second times out.

This is the technical explaination. As to why this is the case, only Microsoft will know. Could be a misconfiguration, or they could have done it with a purpose. Who knows...